# SQL- How to Sum from table

Tags: mysql

I currently have the below data :

```
  ID     state     
 -------------------
   1    display           
   2    display       
   3    display       
   4    display       
   5     no         
   6     yes
```

I know how to Sum of all ID :

```
SELECT SUM(id)  FROM Message;
```

But , I have latest id of display `(id = 4 here)`.

I'm trying to sum of message which state of them isn't `display`.

**Edited:**

I want to sum of message which their ID is bigger than 4.

Any suggestion?

Comment: simple put where condtion

Comment: Your questions are really basic. So you are learning SQL, but didn't know that there is a WHERE clause??? You read the chapter on aggregation before getting to the WHERE clause? And when shown a WHERE clause with a not equal comparision (`state <> 'display'`), you absolutely have no idea how to build a greater than comparision (`id > 4`)? Rather than asking here you should better continue reading your SQL book. It doesn't end on page one you know.

Comment: How is the sum of the ids useful for anything? That's like multiplying telephone numbers!!?!? And @thorsten while your criticisms are valid, it's also obvious that in the production environment the op would not know the id of the latest 'display' state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT SUM(id) FROM Message WHERE state !='display' and id > 4;
```

Comment: i answered the same but OP is sleeping :)

Comment: @Suchit How to sum of messages which their id is bigger than 4?

Comment: @afn in where clause add `id > 4` .you can use having id > 4 also but i won't prefer this.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
SELECT SUM(id) FROM Message WHERE state <> 'display' AND id > 4;
```

Comment: How to sum of messages which their id is bigger than 4?

Comment: @afn you can check Suchit's answer

Answer (score 0):

Select state, count(*) as count
From message
Where Id > 4
Group by state

If you want counts to be greater then 10

Having count > 10